# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/players/1. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, redux

I am building a react-native app with rails api. I have a players_controller with create, index, update actions. I can do all things(create, index, update) from postman. But when I tried form fetch request from react action. I could only index and create player model. On update I get this error in debugger console.

```
:3000/players/1:1 OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/players/1
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/players/1. Response 
for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

in Rails my players_controller.rb

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
 respond_to :json
 def index
  @players = Player.find_by(player_id: params[:player_id])
  player = Player.all
  render json: @players
 end
def create
  player = Player.new(player_params)
  if player.save
    render json: player, status: 201
  else
  render json: { errors: player.errors }, status: 422
  end
end

def update
 player = Player.find(params[:id])
 player.update(player_params)
 if player.save
   render json: player, status: 201
 else
 render json: { errors: player.errors }, status: 422
 end
end

private

def player_params
 params.require(:player).permit(:username, :profile_pic, :player_id)
end
end
```

In my react-native app I have action

```
export const profilePicUpdate = (player, profile) => (dispatch) => {
const obj = player;
obj.profile_pic = profile;
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/players/${player.id}`, {
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    obj
  })
}).then(() => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'PROFILE_PIC_UPDATE',
    payload: profile
  });
  NavigatorService.navigate('Profile');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error', error);
});
};
```

Comment: please post your routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is need to see your roues.rb file, but also maybe you need to add 
gem 'rack-cors'
and set up it

`Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end`

in `config/initializers/cors.rb`